# Prevent noodles from sticking when leftover in fridge

Tags: food-preservation, noodles

and sorry for the basic question but I'm a... basic cook.

I'm trying to replicate a simple meal I buy at the local shop which is fine when eating hot, but when cooling, leaving in the fridge and eating during the week, the noodles always stick together.

[These are the noodles I use](http://www.sharwoods.us/Our-Ranges/Chinese-Range/Medium-Egg-Noodles) - and I cook it with chicken, sweet chilli sauce and other veg etc. I've read drizzling in olive oil helps but it didn't help me, so I assumed that's when cooking and not when putting into tubs to keep during the week.

I have also read that instead you should cook the noodles separate, then rinse them - now I haven't tried this yet as when cooking my noodles I add herbs/spices etc, wouldn't then rinsing wash the flavours off the noodles?

Or am I supposed to rinse first and then throw into the saucepan with the flavours from the chicken etc, and then add my flavourings?

Thanks in advance!

(I will eat the noodles cold the next day, no need to reheat).

Comment: Did you try following any popular recipe? or the cooking method mentioned on the packet of noodles you use?

Comment: The oil 'trick' is to cook them in boiling water, drain (possibly rinse to remove loose starch), and then toss with oil.  But then your sauce doesn't always stick well.

Comment: @Joe That's the Italian method and what I was going to answer.  You want to go first? (ping me here and I'll come back and upvote)

Comment: @Fabby : it might be an Italian American style ... Most Italians on here say that's something that no true Italian will do, as it messed us sauce adhesion.  And they're more likely to pull the pasta early (before it gets too sticky) and cook it the last couple of minutes in the sauce.  But I don't think it's a good answer, I was just commenting on the 'drizzling in olive oil' bit in his question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cooking method for the [noodles](http://www.sharwoods.us/Our-Ranges/Chinese-Range/Medium-Egg-Noodles) you're using says:

> 1. Allow 1 block of noodles per person.
> 2. Plunge them into a pan of boiling water and simmer for 4 minutes.
> 3. Drain well and toss in a splash of soy sauce.
>
> When serving as part of a stir-fry: Rinse in cold water, drain, then add to the wok, tossing all ingredients together just before serving for a spectacular stir-fry with masses of flavour.

The first part of the method i.e. cooking the noodles separately is for when you want to use them plain.

The second paragraph of the method is what would be applicable in your situation. Cook your chicken/veg with the flavorings. Rinse the noodles in cold water, drain and then add to the pan mixing everything together just before serving.

When you cook the noodles with other ingredients without rinsing the noodles first, the starch washed off the noodles causes them to stick. So Yes, you're supposed to rinse them first.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, a pan for the chicken/veg etc, a pan for just the noodles in boiling water. Boil them until cooked, place into a colander and then wash them under a tap (moving them around), then place them into the chicken/veg pan? Sorry for clarifying for something so basic!

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just make sure, you don't over-cook them while boiling. No need to be sorry. You're just learning new things!

Answer (score 1):

When using noodles of this sort for a stir-fry, I don't even simmer them. I just soak them in boiling water from a kettle for a few minutes to soften, moving them about with a fork or chopsticks a couple of times to separate. Then  I strain but don't rinse, and then dress evenly with only just enough sesame oil to keep them from sticking. They can be prepared ahead and allowed to cool, if that's convenient.

It's very easy to overcook noodles, so for me, they go into the fry last, really just to heat through, just before whatever finishing sauce is blended in.